# Replace pipe character "|" with escaped pip character "\|" in string in bash script

Tags: bash, tr

I am trying to replace a pipe character in an String with the escaped character in it:

Input: **"text|jdbc"**
Output: **"text\|jdbc"**

I tried different things with tr:

```
echo "text|jdbc" | tr "|" "\\|"
...
```

But none of them worked.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`tr` is good for one-to-one mapping of characters (read "translate").
`\|` is two characters, you cannot use `tr` for this. You can use `sed`:

```
echo 'text|jdbc' | sed -e 's/|/\\|/'
```

This example replaces one `|`. If you want to replace multiple, add the `g` flag:

```
echo 'text|jdbc' | sed -e 's/|/\\|/g'
```

An interesting tip by [@JuanTomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6282011/juan-tomas) is to use a different separator character for better readability, for example:

```
echo 'text|jdbc' | sed -e 's_|_\\|_g'
```

Comment: When I'm using sed with a pattern with slashes or backslashes, I like to use `_` as a delimiter: `echo "text|jdbc" | sed -e 's_|_\\|_'`

Comment: @JuanTomas not a bad idea, added to my post

Comment: [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64646/72988) `tr` works although 2 characters in the search.

Comment: @janos, you wrote `one-to-one mapping` with tr, but the link shows it works with two-to-one: `tr "\n" "|"` because of `\n`

Comment: @Timo `\n` is a newline character. It's written with two characters, but really it's just one.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the fact that `|` is a special character in `bash`, which means the `%q` modifier used by `printf` will escape it for you:

```
$ printf '%q\n' "text|jdbc"
text\|jdbc
```

A more general solution that doesn't require `|` to be treated specially is

```
$ f="text|jdbc"
$ echo "${f//|/\\|}"
text\|jdbc
```

`${f//foo/bar}` expands `f` and replaces every occurance of `foo` with `bar`. The operator here is `/`; when followed by another `/`, it replaces all occurrences of the search pattern instead of just the first one. For example:

```
$ f="text|jdbc|two"
$ echo "${f/|/\\|}"
text\|jdbc|two
$ echo "${f//|/\\|}"
text\|jdbc\|two
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `awk`:

```
echo "text|jdbc" | awk -F'|' '$1=$1' OFS="\\\|"
```